# How can I define a trait with arguments and return types like Fn?

Tags: syntax, rust, closures, traits

I'm confused by the following code ([Listing 13-9](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html)):

```
struct Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(i32) -> i32,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<i32>,
}
```

I understand that `Fn` is a trait, but usually a trait has no argument and returned type. How can I define a trait like `Fn`?

I tried to look [at the definition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) (actually it's `FnOnce`, but `Fn` has `FnMut` bound and `FnMut` has `FnOnce` bound...), but I'm still confused. What is the meaning of that `<Args>`? Then also [something written about it in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html); but I do not understand it:

> Where `Fn(a, b, c) -> d` is itself just sugar for the unstable *real* `Fn` trait

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I define a trait with arguments and return types like Fn?

If you mean the syntax `MyTrait(A) -> B`, you cannot. Traits with "arguments" and "return types" are special and are restricted to the `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` traits. This is hard-coded into the compiler. There's even a specific error message for it:

```
error: parenthetical notation is only stable when used with `Fn`-family traits (see issue #29625)
 --> src/main.rs:5:8
  |
5 |     A: MyTrait(A) -> B,
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

That being said, this syntax desugars into the standard trait syntax. You can see what `FnOnce` is from the docs:

```
pub trait FnOnce<Args> {
    type Output;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

The compiler converts `Fn(A, B, C) -> Z` into `Fn<(A, B, C), Output = Z>`. `Args` is a standard trait generic type parameter and `Output` is a standard associated type. The `"rust-call"` ABI is some internal compiler machinery that makes this a bit more efficient and can be ignored most of the time.

You are completely allowed to create your own traits with generic parameters and associated types. You just are not allowed to use the parenthetical notation.

Comment: Hey can this error message be modified to be more in laymans terms? Something akin to you have used `()` for in a trait when you should have used `<>`? 'parenthetical notation' means diddly to me!

Comment: @JGFMK you are encouraged to file issues on the [Rust repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust) for such things.